# How to make a button go to the previous visited page, other than a specific page using a jQuery Mobile button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Currently I have a button on the top of my page that when you click it, will take you to a specific page. Here is the code:

```
<div data-inline="true"><a href="#Back" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left">Back</a>
```

Instead, I would like it to take me to the previous visited page. This might get confusing but I will try to explain. I have a site that is set up as an app, so when you click on tab, it will take you to another page. The back button coded for each section is to take you to the parent of that tab. Although, there are sometimes links within the page that take you to completely different areas of the site.

I would like to be able to click the back button and it take me back to the page I was on beforehand, and not the parent of the current page. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data-rel="back"`:

```
<div data-inline="true"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left">Back</a>
```